# Is this the "right" way to write an Angular custom directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, directive

...and is a custom directive the "right" way to accomplish my goal?

I have an app that was just converted to Angular (by someone else as I am an extreme noob) that displays 3 pages (more accurately, 3 sets of content) and uses a template and HTML partials to do so.

Before the conversion, each of these 3 pages loaded via a GET request and reloaded the entire page with each request. Each time a page loaded, a few jQuery plugins were attached to elements within the page. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cntnr_photos').mCustomScroll();
    $("image[rel='tooltip']").applyTooltips();
    // ...and a couple more
});
```

Now that these pages are assembled and displayed with Anglar, the entire page no longer reloads every time a new page is requested... just the "contents" of the page reload and the javascript above that used to run every time only runs the 1st time an application page is requested.

Through some research, I learned that a custom directive was the correct, "Angular" to apply it to each of the 3 sets of content in the app.

Here is what I came up with:

```
app.directive('init',
        function() {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

                    var base = $(element);

                    var initHscroll = function(cntnrID, options) {
                        var opts_dflt = {
                            contentTouchScroll : 20,
                            axis : "x",
                            autoExpandScrollbar : true,
                            theme : "dark",
                            scrollButtons : {
                                enable : true
                            },
                            mouseWheel : {
                                enable : false
                            },
                            advanced : {
                                autoExpandHorizontalScroll : true
                            }
                        }

                        var opts = typeof options !== 'undefined' ? options : opts_dflt;
                        var oCntnr = typeof cntnrID !== 'undefined' ? base.find($(cntnrID)) : base.find($('#cntnr_photos'));

                        oCntnr.mCustomScrollbar(opts);
                    };

                    var initTooltips = function(selector) {
                        var sel = typeof selector !== 'undefined' ? selector : "img[rel='tooltip']";

                        base.find(sel).applyTooltips();
                    }

                    scope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function(event, next, current) {
                        initHscroll();
                        initTooltips();
                       // jcf.customForms.replaceAll();
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Did interpret what I read correctly that a custom directive is appropriate here? And if so, does mine seem to be in line with best practices and done the "right" way?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but in Angularjs you have to call your GET request in a service then use that response data in a controller to render the data in your template. You use directives in angular to manipulate the DOM or HTML code once you have rendered your data.

Comment: Yes, that's all happening. I have been tasked with finding a way to apply these jQuery plugins to each view rendered by the controller. I am applying the directive I posted to one of the outermost <div>s with `<div id="wrappr" init>`

Comment: Make you sure you have jquery before angularjs. I assume its not working and do you see any errors? You will have to provide more insight into whats going on.

Comment: It is working. I am asking about whether or not this is the "right" way to apply jQuery plugins to various DOM elements? or is there a more widely accepted/utilized way of doing this? Is there anything jumping out at you that screams "poor technique" or not in keeping with best practice?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. I have never used jQuery plugins with  AngularJs.